# With the Maven Swagger code generation plugin, how can I generated DTOs from schemas with proper required annotations (e.g. @NotNull)?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, maven-plugin, swagger-codegen, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I'm using the Maven swagger codegen plugin (v 3.0.17).  I was curious how, if possible, would I configure the plugin so that when my DTOs are generated from my defined schemas, the required attributes are marked with "@NotNull" or "@NotEmpty" annotations. I have this defined in my inputSpec .yml

```
...
components:
    ...
  schemas:
    ...
    MyObjectDTO:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int32
          readOnly: true
        groupId:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          required: true 
    ...
      required:
        - groupId
      description: my object
```

The generated DTO looks like

```
@Schema(description = "my object")
@Validated
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "com.myco.codegen.SpringCodegen", date = "2022-07-22T15:18:11.693263100-05:00[America/Chicago]")
public class MyObjectDTO   {

    ,,,
  @JsonProperty("groupId")
  private Integer groupId = null;
```

When this DTO is passed to a Spring REST controller which is @Validated, if the "groupId" field isn't populated, I would like validation to fail, and ultimately a 400 (bad request) error to be returned.

Maven plugin configuration is

```
            <configuration>
                <language>com.myco.myproject.mypackage.swagger.codegen.OAS3SpringCodegen
                </language>
                <apiPackage>com.myco.myproject.mypackage.api
                </apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>com.myco.mypackage.api.model
                </modelPackage>
                <languageSpecificPrimitives>true</languageSpecificPrimitives>                   
                <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                <generateApiDocumentation>true</generateApiDocumentation>
                <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                <importMappings>
                    <importMapping>LocalDateTime=OffsetDateTime</importMapping>
                </importMappings>
                <configOptions>
                    <throwsException>true</throwsException>                     
                    <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                    <java8>false</java8>
                    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                    <sourceFolder>.</sourceFolder>
                    <useTags>true</useTags>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
```

Comment: have you checked your getters? there might be the annotation `@nonnull` getting applied on getters with `@ApiModelProperty(required = true,....)`

Comment: Please add the full `dependencies` and `plugins` sections of your POM

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation`
(or just `javax.validation:validation-api` / `jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api`) dependency to your project and enable `useBeanValidation` in the plugin configuration:

```xml
<configuration>
    ...
    <configOptions>
        ...
        <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
    </configOptions>
</configuration>
```

Also, try changing the language parameter to the standard `<language>java</language>` or `<language>spring</language>`.

Comment: Hi, Gave this a try but no validation annotations were added to the generated DTOs (only annotations on each field continue to be the @JsonProperty annotations)

Comment: BTW, what's in `com.myco.myproject.mypackage.swagger.codegen.OAS3SpringCodegen`? Won't the standard `<language>spring</language>` do for your case?